# Components doesn't re-reload when props value changes with multi pages react

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-hooks

I'm experimenting with the multi page react, using react-router-dom package and I'm stuckin in a problem. I have 2 pages (2 paths). I  want to display

item2

element on the Header ("/" path) components when I click the button on Main ("/main" path) components. But the Header components not re-render when the props.showItem2 was changed. I tried with useContext but the same problem appeares.
The code below perfectly work on a single page version. I assume I miss something when use route.
`Here is my code

```
// App.js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Main from "./Main";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import "./App.css";

function App() {
  const [showItem2, setShowItem2] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setShowItem2(prev => !prev);
  };

  console.log(showItem2);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={<Header showItem2={showItem2} />}
        />
        <Route path="/main" element={<Main handleClick={handleClick} />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
//Main.js
import React from "react";

function Main(props) {
  const clickHandler = () => {
    props.handleClick();
  };
  return <button onClick={clickHandler}>Main</button>;
}

export default Main;
```

```
//Header.js
import React from "react";

const Header = React.memo((props) => {
  console.log("Header re-rendered, showItem2=", props.showItem2);
  return (
    <header>
      <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        {props.showItem2 && <li>item2</li>}
        <li>item3</li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  );
});

export default Header;
```

Comment: The issue you are facing is due to the fact that the `Header component` is only **rendered once when the app loads**, and it **doesn't re-render when the state of showItem2 changes in the App component**. This is because the **Header component is only associated with the "/" route**, which is only rendered once when the app loads. When you navigate to the `"/main"` route and click the button to **change the state of showItem2**, the **Header component doesn't re-render** because it is **not associated with that route**.